# Azure mysql - migration from onpromise to the cloud

Tags: mysql, azure

I am trying to migrate my onpromise MySQL to Azure MySQL. I have a dump file of around 7 GB, and it takes about 3 hours to finish the import process(I have changed the database parameters). This is too slow for production, so  I am looking for a better way to finish the import.

Now, I am trying to use the Azure Database Migration Service. The onpromise database is 192.168.6.9:3306. Is it possible to let this database be accessible for the Azure Database Migration Service?

Or can it import the data by running the dump file first and then use a bin log that syncs it locally to the cloud?

Comment: This is because your system is too slow, but such import you do only oncce and then import only the changes

Comment: If a goal is to dump data, I would suggest using Azure Data Factory PIpeline. First, fetch all the tables' names using the script task, then loop over each table using the ForEach task and within the ForEach activity use the Copy Data Activity. Set the batch count for ForEach activity to any number under 30, whatever number you set for ForEach activity, will be pulling the data from that number of tables in parallel. Also, for a time being stop any other service which is not related to MySQL and if possible scale it for a time being as it is just one-time activity.